# Database of the central admin no longer exists

Tags: central-administration

how can I reaccess or restore only the central admin BD (MOSS 2007) if the database and the server no longer exists? (Bd on a old server)

All others webapps still work (bd on a new server) but when I try to go to the central admin I receive an error  "cannot display this application". On the logs, the CA can't reach the "database name" from SQLSERVER123(old server) ...

Can I run the wizard again to repair this? what will happen to another webapp?

Thanks

sorry for my poor english  :)
Julie

Answer (score 1):

Try to provision the CA
 psconfig.exe -cmd adminvs -provision -port 888 -windowsauthprovider onlyusentlm